# Get the inner elements of the richtextbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I had a rich textbox like this:

```
      <RichTextBox x:Name="richtextbox">
            <RichTextBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <HyperlinkButton  x:Name="txtnam" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="3" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txttextblock" Width="452"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </RichTextBox.Template>
        </RichTextBox>
```

Now i want to insert a text in textblock using button click event.If textblock is out of richtextbox we can access like this.txttextblock.text ="content". But how access this textblock now in button click.Can any one please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "FindName" method to find sub elements.

```
((TextBlock)richtextbox.FindName("txttextblock")).Width
```

Output : 452